# No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped when invoking a bean from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, cdi, weld-se

While using Weld-SE 2.1.2.Final to obtain a bean and to invoke it from a thread, I encounter the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

My bean is annotated with @RequestScooped. If I annotate @ApplicationScoped then it works fine, but I need to keep @RequestScooped.

Here is a reproducer :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Weld weld = new Weld();
    WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    final MyPojo pojo = container.instance().select(MyPojo.class).get();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(pojo.ping());   // This call fails
        }
    };
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println(pojo.ping()); // This call succeed
    weld.shutdown();

}

@RequestScoped
public class MyPojo {
 public String ping() {
    return "pong";
 }
}
```

Did you encounter this behavior?  Any idea to make this work please?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In this case Weld is using unbound RequestContext that is associated with a thread ([RequestContext](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/javadoc/2.1/weld-api/index.html?org/jboss/weld/context/RequestContext.html)). You need to manually initialize new RequestContext in a thread that You're creating, this works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Weld weld = new Weld();
    final WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
    RequestContext requestContext= container.instance().select(RequestContext.class, UnboundLiteral.INSTANCE).get();
    requestContext.activate();

    final MyPojo pojo = container.instance().select(MyPojo.class).get();

    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            RequestContext requestContext= container.instance().select(RequestContext.class, UnboundLiteral.INSTANCE).get();
            requestContext.activate();
            System.out.println("1" + pojo.ping()); 
        }
    };
    t.start();
    t.join();
    System.out.println("2" + pojo.ping());
    weld.shutdown();

}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me unless I duplicate request context creation and activation before the thread creation. I believe this was the case in a previous edition of your answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have enough reputation to do voteup. I marked the answer as a good one.

Comment: By now you can also use the annotation `javax.enterprise.context.control.ActivateRequestContext`